# Is there TAB control and how to open page2 from button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there TAB control and how to open page2 from button click ?

On asp.net ?

I work with C# and Visual Studio 2008 and ASP.NET

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard ASP.NET controls that ship with the .NET Framework do not include a tab control. However you can find a number of implementations on the internet, I would suggest you look the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

As for the button click redirecting to page2 you can handle the button click event on the server side and use a Response.Redirect("page2.aspx") to redirect the users browser to the desired page. Other alternatives exist like using an anchor (link) which will request the second page directly.

Answer (score 0):

Set the SelectedTab property to the index of the tab you want to display in the click event of your button.